# Considering the number $\frac{3}{7}$ written under the form $\frac{3}{7} = 0,a_1a_2a_3\dots$ compute $a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots+a_{2013}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve:
Considering the number $\frac{3}{7}$ written under the form $\frac{3}{7} = 0,a_1a_2a_3\dots$ compute $a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots+a_{2013}$.

I've only computed the number $\frac{3}{7}$...$\frac{3}{7}=(428571)$ but from here I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Hint. Count how many of each digit occur among the first $2013$ in that repeating decimal. (Perhaps do this first for the first $20$ digits, for practice.)

Comment: those 6 digits keep repeating forever and 2013 = 6*335+3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we have $$2013 = 335\cdot 6+3$$

the sum is $$335\cdot (4+2+8+5+7+1)+4+2+8=9059$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_1+a_2+...+a_{2013}\\=a_1+a_2+...+a_{2010}+a_{2011}+a_{2012}+a_{2013}\\=335\times (4+2+8+5+7+1)+4+2+8\\=9045+4+2+8=9059$$